# Mathematical Induction and the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic

Tags: combinatorics, induction

Prove if $n$ is an integer, $n \geq 2$, then either $n$ is prime or else can be factored into a product of primes.

I don't quite understand (at all) how to connect this to the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, so ANY help would be appreciated!

Comment: This IS the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetics (minus the part on uniqueness of the factorisation).

Comment: Somehow I was brought up to believe that the fundamental theorem of arithmetic _is_ the uniqueness assertion: A number cannot have more than one prime factorization.

Comment: @ Michael Hardy: Well yes! The existence argument is (very) straightforward so the "non trivial" and important part of the theorem is uniqueness.
@Jacob http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic contains the required answer.